# Ionic Cordova Linking to internal views (pages)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hyperlink, ionic3

I have an Ionic project. On my home page I want to link to another internal view (page). Specifically when the user clicks an image I want it to navigate to the pray.html page.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="margin-left: -10px; width: calc(100% + 20px);">
      <a style="display:block;" href="#PrayPage">
        <img src="../assets/img/praycomplinebutton.png" style="display: block; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
      </a>
    </div>
```

Currently when I try this I get the following error:

```
Runtime Error:
Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert

Stack:
c@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13199
http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:12547
_fireError@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:43691:22
_failed@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:43679:24
onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4480:43
run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4146
http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13734
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4471:47
runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4841
o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:1898
invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10674
```

I know this can be done.. I just can't find any documentation on how to do it. I'd appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-a-button-open-another-page/42645/11

Comment: Assuming your are using ionic3. You can go through ionic navigation tutorial to understand the pages linking.

http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-adding-pages-and-navigation/

Comment: Thanks @MayankKumar. That worked.

Comment: @Brent  - Hey, could you mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using ionic3. You can go through [ionic navigation tutorial](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-adding-pages-and-navigation/) to understand the pages linking.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the "href" attribute from the anchor tag. ionic 2 causing view error due to this.

Comment: I don't understand the neg votes... this is A (not THE) valid solution...

Comment: bro this answer was w.r.t to the context of question sited above.

Comment: WHAT? I had the problem of the post, and this was the solution... I mean, maybe it's not the only problem that can cause that symptom, but it's a possibility... why the negative vote???

Comment: @AriWaisberg, I solved the above problem using this solution. i didn't give any neg vote. i hope this solution will work for others too.